# Getting Runtime error 9 - Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting run time error when I run the following code.

```
Sub em()
    Dim strlogin As String
    Dim strnextlogin As String

    For i = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        strlogin = Sheets("Untitled").cell(i, 1)
        strnextlogin = Sheets("Untitled").cell(i + 1, 1)
        If (strlogin = strnextlogin) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to delete the 1st value in the duplicates.

Comment: Can you say what line gives the error, my assumption is the code cannot find sheets("Untitled")

Answer (score 5):

I see couple of problems

1. You are using `xlDown` to find the last cell. I would recommend seeing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) link on how to find last row.
2. You are getting the error `Runtime Error 9 Subscript out of range` because Excel cannot find the sheet that you are referring to. Please ensure that the sheet exists. If you can visually see the `Untitled` sheet then I believe the sheet name has leading or trailing spaces.
3. Once you solve that issue, the next error that you will get is `Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`. And that is because you are using `cell` instead of `cells`. For example `.cell(i, 1)` should be `.Cells(i, 1)` and `.cell(i + 1, 1)` should be `.Cells(i + 1, 1)`
4. Declare your objects else if `Sheets("Untitled")` is not the active sheet then `Rows(i).Delete` will delete from the wrong sheet ;)
5. Avoid deleting the rows in a loop. It will only make your code slower. See how I have used `delRange` in the code below.

Fix these things and you will be good to go

**Note:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub em()
    Dim delRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, LRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Untitled")

    With ws
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LRow To 2 Step -1 '~~> Even 2 To LRow will work :)
            If .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
                If delRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```